# How to keep floating div inside frame of parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing several other divs with setting float:left. Now I want a frame around all of them, so i put a border on the parent div, but the floating ones "flow" out of the frame...

CSS:

```
.rendering {
    padding-left:10pt;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.column {
    float:left;
    padding-left:10pt;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="rendering">
    <div class="column">
        <img class="ImagePlugin" src="some-image">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <span class="phone">999</span>
        <span class="name">Assange</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What can I do (in CSS) to keep them inside the parent frame?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

add `overflow: hidden` to your parent `<div>` - http://jsfiddle.net/5AVA8/

```
.rendering {
    padding-left:10pt;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Just out of interest what's the advantage of this over the clear div? Is it just no new mark up?

Comment: @SpaceBears exactly, for simple things like this it's more suitable than the `clearfix`

Comment: the opening question on this post was straight to the point. he made it clear about what he was trying to do. Adding overflow:hidden; to the ccs (the answer given by Zoltan Toth) is what worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You're not clearing the floats. If you change your code to this it will solve your problem.

```
.rendering {
    padding-left:10pt;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.column {
    float:left;
    padding-left:10pt;
}

.clear {
     clear: both;   
}

<div class="rendering">
    <div class="column">
        <img class="ImagePlugin" src="some-image">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <span class="phone">999</span>
        <span class="name">Assange</span>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

See the example I've set up here - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/RQNDr/

For more information on the clear property - http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Comment: Image is broken

Answer (score 4):

You must 'clear the float', there are various methods of 'float clearing'. Some solutions involve CSS only, my preferred solution (disliked by some people because it adds extra markup) is to add a 'clearing div', it works as follows:

```
<div class="rendering">
    <div class="column">
        <img class="ImagePlugin" src="some-image">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <span class="phone">999</span>
        <span class="name">Assange</span>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

See the second from last line.